# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal problem

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication

To cut whole thing short, here is the WPF startup and probably where the problem lies.

```cs
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            CustomPrincipal customPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal();
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(customPrincipal);

            //Show main window and inject dependencies
            AuthViewModel viewModel = new AuthViewModel(new AuthenticationService());
            IMainViews mainWindow = new MainWindow(viewModel);
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
```

I set `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(customPrincipal)` where customPrincipal is my own implementation.

The thing is, it works... for main window at least, then through debugger i put some breakpoints on different events, upon observing Thread.CurrentPrincipal on those breakpoints it seems it somehow evaluated the whole thing to null later on. While when the whole MainWindow initalization is in process Thread.CurrentPrincipal is customPrincipal as it should be. After mainWindow.Show() i dont have Principal anymore.

AppDomain should set any thread on app domain to use the principal set on app startup?

Possible things to note is that i use Prism and this is done on .netcore 3 WPF if that makes any difference.

Update 1: IPrincipal implementation

```
public class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    private CustomIdentity _identity;

    public CustomIdentity Identity
    {
        get { return _identity ?? new AnonymousIdentity(); }
        set { _identity = value; }
    }

    IIdentity IPrincipal.Identity
    {
        get { return this.Identity; }
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        return _identity.Role == role;
    }
}
```

AnonymousIdentity() just returns empty strings for all properties including Name which also works just fine for first window.

Comment: `AppDomain` is limited on .NET Core by design, MS recommends to use `AssemblyLoadContext`. But `SetThreadPrincipal` method is there, according to [sources](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/AppDomain.cs). Can you share your implementation of principal?

Comment: I added IPrincipal implementation to update 1 in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For now it seems that i misunderstood how exactly `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal` works(or that is exactly how it works hmm)

I added a checking for weather a `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is null. 
In case it is, I instantiate a new `CustomIdentity()` object with info whether user is indeed signed in or not and then instantiate either `AnonymousIdentity()` or return the actual user.

It kinda kills the point of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal` but i just could not get it to attach to `Thread` for a whole domain and switch it upon user input without it ever evaluating to null, which I initially thought is the main purpose of this method.

I believe this not be a real answer but rather a hacky workaround(with this i can actually delete the whole `AppDomain` setup) so if someone has more experience with this please share your opinion. Thanks